# Expandable ListView Grouping Items by Year / Month

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, expandablelistview

I have a long list of Objects I am retrieving from an SQLite database. For simplification, let's say an `Event` object has the properties `Date`, `Name`, and `Location`.

I can have a chronological `ListView` of `Event`s using the following list adapter and fetching `Event`s from the database sorted by `Date`.

```
public class ImageListButtonListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageListButtonListItem> {

    public ImageListButtonListAdapter(Context c, List<ImageListButtonListItem> items) {
        super(c, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageListButtonView itemView = (ImageListButtonView)convertView;
        if (null == itemView)
            itemView = ImageListButtonView.inflate(parent);
        itemView.setItem(getItem(position));
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Now this list is very long, and I want to further structure the list using an `ExpandableListView`, and group the `Event` items by month. Examples I found creating a list adapter derived from `BaseExpandableListAdapter` typically included predefined groups and group names. I just have one large group of items each containing a (Joda Time) `LocalDate`, based on which I can add a calculated property `YearMonth` that can be used for sorting.

My first thought was to pass the entire list to the adapter and let the adapter determine groups, and assign items to the groups upon creation of the adapter. But I'm afraid that processing the entire list this way, creating the groups and assigning items to these groups before the list can be shown would be a costly process in an already performance-sensitive view.

I can imagine this to be a rather common scenario, and that there is a more elegant way to solve it. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Could you add the code for your datamodel into the question also. Why can't you order your data in a correct manner before putting it into your `ListView`?

Comment: Yes, that was my approach now. And I got it to work somehow with Lollipop and later. On older devices the list is still empty. I'll clean some of the code and add it to the question it in a short while. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question with the current code. I hope the fragment reveals sufficient information about the data model - trying to avoid posting excessive amounts of code.

Comment: Without knowing how much data you have, I would recommend you went one step further back and looked at your `DatabaseManager` and looked into if you could select the data and group it correctly before retrieving it from the database. One thing I've always learned was that whatever work you could handover to the database, you should, because the database engines are mostly superior in speed to programming languages like Java.

Comment: @Darwind OK, fixed a small unrelated issue (mostly in my head :)  ). The code is actually working independent of the android version. I can remove the additional info again as the answer does not really depend on that (or it actually is the answer). Since you went through the trouble of looking at the issue, which I'm very grateful for, and basically answered it with your first comment, would you like to post a formal answer, so I can give credit?

Comment: Ok, so I've added an answer - not the most fulfilling answer, but still :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add an answer.

Instead of trying to order the data after it's fetched from the database, I'd recommend grouping the data correctly, by changing the way you query the database.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Yes, thank you. The functional issue was resolved by your first comment. Indeed the `ExpandableListView` does not include the "Intelligence" to group items by a given criterion. So you need to "manually" group the data into portions with headers. That is what I needed to know. Performance is OK, and there are several improvements that can be done: 1. handle the grouping in the `DatabaseManager` and 2. (as you suggest) use smart queries to group it. Now there are two additional iterations on the entire data set on top of the query.1. is easily done. 2. might be subject for another question.

Answer (score 1):

Darwind's comments and answer answered the question in principle. For anyone interested in the code I add this answer.

Preparing groups and children before creating the `ListView` is the right approach. As indicated in Darwin's answer additional performance gain might be achieved by the way the data is retrieved from the database (not included here). Code now is as follows:

```
public class EventsListFragment extends ExpandableListFragment{

    (...)

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        dbManager = new DatabaseManager(getActivity());
        mEvents = dbManager.GetEvents();

        mItems.clear();
        mGroups.clear();
        mChildGroups.clear();

        ArrayList<ImageListButtonListItem> childGroup = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = mEvents.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {

            LocalDate date = mEvents.get(i).getDate();
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.longDate();
            String date =  dtf.print(date);
            String name = mEvents.get(i).getEventName();
            String location = mEvents.get(i).getLocation();
            String imagePath = (...)
            ImageListButtonListItem item = new ImageListButtonListItem(date, name, location, imagePath);

            // List category (sorted by months).
            YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth(date.getYear(), date.getMonthOfYear());

            if(mGroups.isEmpty()) {
                mGroups.add(yearMonth);
            } else if(!mGroups.contains(yearMonth)) {
                mChildGroups.add(childGroup);
                mGroups.add(yearMonth);
                childGroup = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            childGroup.add(item);
        }
        if (!childGroup.isEmpty()) {
            mChildGroups.add(childGroup);
        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    (...)
}
```

-

```
public class MonthExpandableImageListButtonListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Object> mChildGroups;
    private List<YearMonth> mGroups;
    public LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public Activity mActivity;

    public MonthExpandableImageListButtonListAdapter(Context context, List<Object> childGroups, List<YearMonth> groups) {
        mContext = context;
        mChildGroups = childGroups;
        mGroups = groups;
    }
    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity act) {
        mInflater = inflater;
        mActivity = act;
    }
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() { return mGroups.size(); }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) { return  ((ArrayList<Object>)mChildGroups.get(groupPosition)).size(); }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) { return null; }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { return null; }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) { return 0; }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { return 0; }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() { return false; }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_month_expandable_list_header, null);
            }
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(mGroups.get(groupPosition).toString());
            ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageListButtonView itemView = (ImageListButtonView)convertView;
        if (null == itemView)
            itemView = ImageListButtonView.inflate(parent);
        itemView.setItem(((ArrayList<ImageListButtonListItem>) mChildGroups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition));
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) { return false; }
}
```